# Best way of Parsing 2 CSV files and printing the common values in a third file

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I am new to Ruby, and I have been struggling with a problem that I suspect has a simple answer. I have two CSV files, one with two columns, and one with a single column. The single column is a subset of values that exist in one column of my first file. Example:

file1.csv:

```
abc,123
def,456
ghi,789
jkl,012
```

file2.csv:

```
def
jkl
```

All I need to do is look up the column 2 value in file1 for each value in file2 and output the results to a separate file. So in this case, my output file should consist of:

```
456
012
```

I’ve got it working this way:

```
pairs=IO.readlines("file1.csv").map { |columns| columns.split(',') }

f1 =[]
pairs.each do |x| f1.push(x[0]) end

f2 = IO.readlines("file2.csv").map(&:chomp)

collection={}
pairs.each do |x| collection[x[0]]=x[1] end

f=File.open("outputfile.txt","w")
  f2.each do |col1,col2| f.puts collection[col1] end
f.close
```

...but there has to be a better way. If anyone has a more elegant solution, I'd be very appreciative! (I should also note that I will eventually need to run this on files with millions of lines, so speed will be an issue.)

Comment: Will the names in `file2` be in the same order as in `file1`? I'm asking because if the order is the same you can implement some optimizations in the final code.

Comment: @Casper, the files that I've been testing are both in the same order, and deduped. However, I happened to have done that as a separate step, so I could also do the ordering and deduping as part of this process.

Comment: Thanks, @Marc & AnkitG for the suggestions. I ran all three versions against my full data set (865k lines in file1, 470k lines in file2, Ruby 1.9.3). Interestingly, the original version was the fastest, by a fairly wide margin (10x, 100+x). I was surprised by this, and it makes me wonder about the efficiency of Ruby's CSV parsing...?

Answer (score 1):

To be as memory efficient as possible, I'd suggest only reading the full file2 (which I gather would be the smaller of the two input files) into memory. I'm using a hash for fast lookups and to store the resulting values, so as you read through file1 you only store the values for those keys you need. You could go one step further and write the outputfile while reading file2.

```
require 'CSV'

# Read file 2, the smaller file, and store keys in result Hash
result = {}
CSV.foreach("file2.csv") do |row|
  result[row[0]] = false
end

# Read file 1, the larger file, and look for keys in result Hash to set values
CSV.foreach("file1.csv") do |row|
  result[row[0]] = row[1] if result.key? row[0]
end

# Write the results
File.open("outputfile.txt", "w") do |f|
  result.each do |key, value|
    f.puts value if value
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Ruby 1.9.3

**Parsing For File 1**

```
data_csv_file1 = File.read("file1.csv")
data_csv1 = CSV.parse(data_csv_file1, :headers => true)
```

**Parsing For File 2**

```
data_csv_file2 = File.read("file2.csv")
data_csv2 = CSV.parse(data_csv_file1, :headers => true)
```

**Collection of names**

```
names_from_sheet1 = data_csv1.collect {|data| data[0]} #returns an array of names

names_from_sheet2 = data_csv2.collect {|data| data[0]} #returns an array of names

common_names = names_from_sheet1 & names_from_sheet2 #array with common names
```

**Collecting results to be printed**

```
 results = [] #this will store the values to be printed
 data_csv1.each {|data| results << data[1] if common_names.include?(data[0]) }
```

**Final output**

```
  f = File.open("outputfile.txt","w")
    results.each {|result| f.puts result }
    f.close
```